# Combining qplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge

I am a total newbie to R and am trying to combine to `qplots` (`ggplot2` package) so that both of the graphs (Stress vs. Strain curves) will become one Stress vs. Strain graph. I have no idea how to do this. Would somebody please help. Below is the code for each individual plot. I have tried using `rbind` but I am not sure if that is relevant here.

```
p1 <- qplot(StrainL,StressL, data=dat2,) + 
      geom_line(aes(colour="Longitudinal"))
p2 <- qplot(StrainC,StressC, data=dat2) + 
      geom_line(aes(colour="Circumferential"))
p3 <- rbind(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Also I am not sure about the coloring of the plots but I also want to have those in different colors. Could anybody help an inexperience undergrad out?

Comment: It's probably easier for this problem to reshape your data to a longer format. That way you can use color/group inside the aes.

Comment: If you would share your data with `dput(dat2)` we could come up with a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions with your data here but this should probably work:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat2) +
        geom_line(aes(x = StrainL, y = StressL, colour = "L")) + 
        geom_line(aes(x = StrainC, y = StressC, colour = "C")) +
xlab("Strain") + 
ylab("Stress") + 
ggtitle("Put your plot's title here") +
scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("L" = "red", "C" = "blue"))
```

Comment: Can I manually change the x and y axis names. With that code Chris, the axis come up as StrainC and Stress C when I want just Stress and Strain. Would you be able to help out with that.

Comment: Perfect I got the title, but I am struggling with the guide_legend. I'm having trouble understanding how to coordinate the different colors to show up in the legend.

Comment: Hi Matt - I edited the answer so it now has a legend. If you want the L to appear as the full word, make sure you change it from L -> fullword in both the geom_line call and in the scale_colour_manual call....As Thomas noted, the answer I gave is not typically how one uses ggplot..However, doing it the proper way would require you to reformat your data which I didn't think you would want to do, so I just gave the "incorrect" yet workable solution to your problem.